# How to assert on on multiple scenarios under 1 test case under a loop using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to perform testing where there are many data in a array and there is multiple `assert`, however what i am experiencing with is if there is 1 message that failed, this will terminate the run.

If putting the code under try and catch, it will show the test case is passed and print the failures. BUT only 1 error as error as well, it doesn't print the following errors.

How do we handle multiple assertion under same test case in pytest?

```
for i in message: 
    assert i.getData == "test", 'the data for this message is wrong'
    assert i.getHead == "test111", 'the head for this message is wrong'
```